# XCode lldb autocomplete

Tags: xcode, lldb

I have searched everywhere but can't seem to get answer.    I am using Xcode 6.1.1.

I recall (possibly incorrectly) autocomplete being available in the lldb debug pane of XCode.  I am currently typing fully all variables and functions; there must be a better way.  Is autocomplete/intellisense available in Xcode?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The autocomplete available today in Xcode debugger console is for lldb commands.  You can type `fr<TAB> v<TAB>` instead of `frame variable`.  The autocomplete in lldb often can complete function names, for instance `br s -n MyClass::MyMeth<TAB>`.  Or for a source file, `br s -f myfil<TAB> -l 15`.  But once you're entering an expression (`expr`, or `p`, or `po`), the code completion you're used to seeing in the text editor panes is not available.